# Can't write serializable object to file

Tags: java, file, object, inheritance, serializable

I have 2 classes:

```
public class BaseEntity<ID> implements Serializable {
    private ID id;

    BaseEntity(ID id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public ID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

and

```
public class Client extends BaseEntity<Integer>{
    private String name;
    private static int lastAssignedId = 0;

    private static int getNewId(){
        lastAssignedId++;
        return lastAssignedId;
    }

    public Client(String name){
        super(getNewId());
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

and i am trying to write object of type Client to a file from a Repository class:

```
public class FileRepository<ID, T extends BaseEntity<ID>> extends InMemoryRepository<ID, T>
```

like so

```
    private void saveToFile(T entity) throws IOException {
        OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(this.file), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        o.writeObject(entity);
        o.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
```

where `file` is an attribute given to the constructor.
I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Model.Client
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at Repository.FileRepository.saveToFile(FileRepository.java:60)
    at Repository.FileRepository.save(FileRepository.java:53)
    at Service.Service.addClient(Service.java:32)
    at View.View.addClient(View.java:199)
    at View.View.handleAdd(View.java:103)
    at View.View.run(View.java:30)
    at main.main(main.java:12)

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Model.Client
```

caused by `o.writeObject(entity);`. I have done some searching online and the fact that the parent class implements serializable should be enough(i also tried adding this to the child, but it did not work either). I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong or missing.

Comment: I didn't have a single issue creating the serializable object. Does the Model class have the public modifier? If not, that could be a cause.

Comment: Are you sure thats the entire exception? Is there possibly more.

Comment: Recompile and redeploy. You aren't running this code. NB You can't append to object streams without special arrangements,

Comment: @Jason What `Model` class? And what makes you think you can't serialize non-public classes?

Comment: @user207421 The exception contains; **Model.Client**. Well I wasn't sure if Client was accessible outside of the Model class but I saw it was the public modifier short after. Mb.